# Linkedin API rest request for profile

Tags: api, linkedin-api, social-networking

recently I've tried to use the LinkedIn API and I've faced a really basic problem, but I couldn't understand the basic usage of this API.

In another APIs you can get information on another person. but in LinkedIn I couldn't figure out how to do it.

I've already tried the urls below, but it didn't work.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/(linkedinID)?format=json
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=(linkedinID)?format=json
```

Thank you people!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you're using a valid access token with your requests. To get one follow the steps here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

To get info on another person's profile make a request with a member ID.

**Request:**

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=MEMBER_ID?format=json
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "firstName": "FIRST_NAME",
    "headline": "HEADLINE",
    "id": "MEMBER_ID",
    "lastName": "LAST_NAME",
    "siteStandardProfileRequest":  {
        "url": "https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=ID&authType=name&authToken=AUTH&trk=TRK"
}
```

You can test out requests here: https://apigee.com/console/linkedin